# How to establish relationship between existing documents using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models in mongoose. The first one is Fruit and another is Person. The fruit model follows the fruitSchema. Which is given below

```
    const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1,
    max: 10
  },
  review: String

});
```

Initially, the person model followed the below schema

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
});
```

Then I created some documents in the Fruit model and saved them.

```
const mango = new Fruit({
  name: "Mango",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Awesome fruit"
});

const grave = new Fruit({
  name: "Grave",
  rating: 9,
  review: "Sour fruit"
});

const pineApple = new Fruit({
  name: "Pine Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Awesome fruit"
});


const orange = new Fruit({
  name: "orange",
  rating: 8,
  review:"orange review"
});
```

After that, I created a Person document and saved it

```
const jhon = new Person({
  name: "John",
  age: 32
});
jhon.save();
```

Next, I changed the PersonSchema as followed

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  favouriteFruit:fruitSchema
});
```

Now I want to connect John with mango, So I wrote this code which is not working. What is the solution?

```
Fruit.find({name: "Mango"}, function(err, mango){

  if(err)
  {
    console.log(err);
  }

  else{
    console.log(mango[0]);
    Person.update({name: "John"},{favouriteFruit: mango[0]});
  }
  mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `PersonSchema` as follow:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  favouriteFruit: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Fruit",
   }
});
```

Comment: but mongodb is a nosql database ‍♀️